# How to implement recursive Node struct?

Tags: rust

Coming from Python, I want to implement a Node struct in Rust similar to the Python code below:

```py
class Node:
    def __init__(self, value: int, next_node: "Node"):
        self.value: int = value
        self.next: Node = next_node

    def __repr__(self):
        return f"Node(value: {self.value}, next: {self.next})"

if __name__ == "__main__":
    a = Node(1, None)
    b = Node(2, None)

    # Link a.next with b
    a.next = b

    print(f"a now: {a}\n")
    # Prints:
    # a now: Node(value: 1, next: Node(value: 2, next: None))

    # Change .value inside b
    b.value = 3

    print(f"a now: {a}")
    print(f"b now: {b}\n")
    # Prints:
    # a now: Node(value: 1, next: Node(value: 3, next: None))
    # b now: Node(value: 3, next: None)

    # Change .value inside a.next
    a.next.value = 4

    print(f"a now: {a}")
    print(f"b now: {b}")
    # Prints:
    # a now: Node(value: 1, next: Node(value: 4, next: None))
    # b now: Node(value: 4, next: None)
```

My implementation so far in Rust is the following:

```rust
#[derive(Debug)]
#[derive(Clone)]
struct Node {
    value: i32,
    next: Option<Box<Node>>,
}

fn main() {
    let mut a = Node { value: 1, next: None };
    let mut b = Node { value: 2, next: None };

    // Box and encapsulate a and b inside Option
    let mut option_a = Some(Box::new(a));
    let mut option_b = Some(Box::new(b));

    // Link a.next with b
    if let Some(ref mut a_unwrapped) = option_a {
        a_unwrapped.next = option_b;
    }
    println!("a now: {:?}", option_a);
    // Prints:
    // a now: Some(Node { value: 1, next: Some(Node { value: 2, next: None }) })
}
```

However, the line `a_unwrapped.next = option_b;` moves the node's `option_b` inside of `a.next` instead of creating a reference. Now I'm no longer able to access `option_b`.

Unrelated to the above, changing a value inside a node would perhaps be possible using:

```rust
if let Some(ref mut b_unwrapped) = option_b {
    b_unwrapped.value = 3;
    // It is desired that a.next.value is now 3 as well
}
```

I want to implement this because I want to create a `Queue` data structure (and perhaps binary trees) without using Rust's `Vec` data structure and without using the `unsafe` keyword, just as a personal challenge.

So far, I was able to build a `Stack` data structure with the linked list approach described [here](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/second-option.html).

As you can see, I struggle to understand how one would implement this.

It seems to me that having more than one reference in Rust pointing at the same object is rather difficult (because of Data Races and Race Conditions), or I am just using the wrong approach.

Comment: If you want to have the node in the list and simultaneously for local modification you will have to consider something like `Option<Rc<Refcell<Node>>>` instead of `Option<Box<Node>>`.

Comment: I'm having trouble trying to implement your suggestion. Do you have a link to an example?

Comment: Have you read [Learn Rust With Entirely Too Many Linked Lists](https://rust-unofficial.github.io/too-many-lists/)?

Comment: Yeah, this is what I have linked. However I stopped reading after about 30-40% in because it got complicated very quickly.
I guess I give it another go.